# Understand mixed model for meta analysis?

Tags: mixed-model, residuals, meta-analysis

I am using a mixed model meta analysis, for combining several studies, more specifically doing a linear model adjusting for covariates within each study, and then pooling the estimated effect size, to have more statistical power. I have been looking into the paper behind the method I will use for the meta analysis:

https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v036i03

(From the paper)

```
2.2. Mixed-effects model
Alternatively, we can include one or more moderators (study-level variables) in the model
that may account for at least part of the heterogeneity in the true eects. This leads to the
4 metafor: Conducting Meta-Analyses in R
mixed-effects model, given by

theta_i = beta_0 + beta_1*x_i1 + ... + beta_p'*x_ip' + u_i (3)

where x_ij denotes the value of the j-th moderator variable for the i-th study and we assume
again that u_i ~ N(0; tau^2). Here, tau^2 denotes the amount of residual heterogeneity among
the true effects, that is, variability among the true effects that is not accounted for by the
moderators included in the model. The goal of the analysis is then to examine to what extent
the moderators included in the model influence the size of the average true effect.
```

And in equation 3, from that paper (the PDF), I am a bit confused about. I assume it is a mixed model, so shouldn't there also be the residuals(`e_i`)? And also what is the distribution of the whole of `u` (the vector). What is the covariance? I assume the covariance models the similarity of the effect sizes of the different studies?

Comment: That is a model for $\theta_i$ not for $y_i$. See the previous equation for $y_i$.